# Is it possible to use expo pushnotification to receive notification on production app react native without having expo go installed?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, expo-notifications

Hope you all are well. Thanks for taking the time to read my question and maybe try to answer it, i really appreciate it.

My question is that I am building an app in react native which i would like to release to play store. I am trying to integrate push notification, i am using expo push notification with subscribed to firebase cloud messaging so i have keys for that which i have integrated inside the app.js. I tried to send push notification from a php script which i run on go daddy domaine. So i received a push notification saying it is coming from Expo Go and the icon of expo go and with the title and body i defined. When i uninstalled expo go, with my app installed on my android device, i did not receive notifications anymore. I would like to know is it possible to use Expo push notifications to release an app to play store and people use it while receiving original notifications ?